# Rebuilds Links Database exception: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable

Tags: sql-database, link-database

When attempting to rebuild the links database on the master database I'm getting the following exception:

```
Job started: RebuildLinkDatabasesIndex|System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback()
  at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderTransaction.Dispose()
  at Sitecore.Links.SqlLinkDatabase.<>c__DisplayClassf.<UpdateLinks>b__d()
  at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.ExecuteNoResult(Action action, Action recover)
  at Sitecore.Links.SqlLinkDatabase.UpdateLinks(Item item, ItemLink[] links)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.RebuildItem(Item item)
  at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.Rebuild(Database database)
  at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.RebuildLinkDatabase.RebuildLinkDatabaseForm.Builder.Build()|Job ended: RebuildLinkDatabasesIndex (units processed: )
```

It suggests in [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140831114920-198423535-cleaning-up-and-optimizing-sitecore-databases/) that this is due to a Sql timeout, controlled by the following setting:

`<setting name="DefaultSQLTimeout" value="00:05:00" />`

But the error appears after approximately 2 minutes, not 5.

Comment: What sitecore version? Do you have multiple CM servers?

Comment: 8.2 update 2. 1 cm & 1 cd (it's a test environment).

Comment: Two solutions suggested on this ticket. Although its fairly old they might be worth a try.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408625/sitecore-database-cleanup-error-timeout